# Trying to install Heroku on Ubuntu gives errors with json and ruby

Tags: ruby, json, ubuntu, heroku

Like the title says, I've been trying to install Heroku. However, as soon as I run any heroku commands I get this in return:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

I ran these commands to install Heroku:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu ./'
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
 sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same error. I think it was an issue with version of Heroku CLI 3.9.4, they just released 3.9.5. After update everything works fine.

To update

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this script

`wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

I've no problem with installation after using this command.